# Windows update error 0x80246016

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-mobile

Since yesterday I have this Window Update error on both my Windows Mobile 10 phone (yes...) and my Windows 7 desktop machine.

On my phone I tried to change networks, and changed the storage to SD card or internal, but I keep getting the same error again and again:

- Error code - `0x80246016`
- Associated message - `Couldn't install, we'll retry shortly`

I'm beginning to think it could be a backend problem.

Does anyone have any information about this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be a Windows Store related issue.

Changing the DNS settings to Google's.

Run Windows Update troubleshooter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It was a Windows strore related issue.
It didn't update yesterday and since this morning the service seems to be all restored.